# CRM 2013 Synchronous Custom Workflow Activity ITracingService

Tags: debugging, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Recently I started testing the 'ITracingService' for the CRM 2013 plugins and custom workflows.
I discovered that the **tracing information** would be displayed on:

- Asynchronous Plugin: Visible on 'Settings > System Jobs';
- Synchronous Plugin: Visible through the exception dialog;
- Asynchronous Workflow: Visible on 'Settings > System Jobs' or 'Background Processes' of the associated record;
- Synchronous Workflow: **NOWHERE TO BE SEEN**....

Although on this [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203239/missing-trace-logs-in-custom-workflow-activity-for-real-time-workflow?answertab=active#tab-top) it is stated that this info may be found on the 'corresponding workflow designer', it only shows the exception message, i.e., the trace log is not present.

Simply put my question is: "Where can I find the tracing log from a synchronous custom workflow activity?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing trace logs in custom workflow activity for Real-Time workflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203239/missing-trace-logs-in-custom-workflow-activity-for-real-time-workflow)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the tracing log by navigating as follows

> Go to Settings >> System Job
>
> Double click on the workflow,  of which you want to see the tracing
>
> Dialogue will appear,  now click on Details
>
> Clicking on Details will expand a view and you will see the tracing in that.